# should a "lamp" object ever be used in cycle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Friendly greetings !

So, i'm kind of a beginner in blender. Used it for many many year (since before v1.0) but on an extremely irregular basis. (a few times a year)

When cycle came out i assumed that every light should be an object with an emissive shader. Make sense, right ?

Now i realize it's actually :

- possible
- may not be totally stupid

... to use a "light" object (point, sun, spot, hemi, area). Or is it ?

---

What are the pro and con of using a light object when using cycle ? when/why do you use it if you do ?

- rendering speed ?
- temporary placeholder ?
- debugging lightning ?
- firefly/noise ?
- easier "light modeling" ? (eg : spot shape (blend/size))
- accuracy/realism ?

Thank you <3

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/area-light-vs-emissive-polygon/8080#8080 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/can-anyone-give-me-some-tips-on-lighting-in-cycles/8660#8660

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89665/29586 for showing benefits of lamp compared to emissive mesh.