# Render always dark

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Total beginner here. I'm working through some basic tutorials but can't figure out why my renders are always so dark. I've tried playing with the lamp and adding more lamps, but can't figure out what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone give me some tips on Lighting in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/can-anyone-give-me-some-tips-on-lighting-in-cycles)

Comment: It would help if you added your .blend file to your post using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You have a gray background which also lites your scene. When you are testing your lights, make your background black. So you only have your actual light objects. then crank up the energy of your lamps and see what is happening

Comment: Just add some nice contrasting light sources and you should be all set. Try and use a sun lamp just to make sure you have stuff configured properly, the other lamps could be inside an object or have too significant falloff

Comment: Have you perhaps disabled the layer containing your lamps?